# Validating a part of request in DataPower

Tags: validation, xsd, ibm-datapower

I have WSDL which can be used to validate complete XML and part of XMLs

MY XML :

```
<Request>
     <Part> .. </part>
     <Part> .. </part>
     <Part> .. </part>
     <Part> .. </part>
     <Part> .. </part>
     <Part> .. </part>
     <Part> .. </part>
</Request>
```

I have configured validation action which is validating complete and throwing as one or more  part is having invalid data.

Requirement is : 
**I have to validate only the part in the above request and remove invalid part before sending to backend.**

Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using extension element / function in the XSLT.

Skeleton:

```
<xsl:template match=Request>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:for-each select="Part">
 <xsl:if test="dp:schema-validate($schema,.) !=''">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

> schema-validate() : Performs a schema validation.
>   Namespace declaration : xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"

Syntax :dp:schema-validate(schema, nodeset)

Parameters : 
   schema : (xs:string) Identifies the XSD schema to perform the validation.
   nodeset:(xs:node-set) Identifies the node set that contains the XML content to validate.
   All arguments are passed as XPath expressions.

Results :the validated node set.

Please refer to [this link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/v3r8m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fxb60%2Fextensionfunctions60.htm) for more info on Extension elements and Functions.